Can we only define Composite Functions & not Composite Relations in general (where the relation may not necessarily be a function)?
I was reading composite functions in a calculus book. Is a composite relation, let's say not a function in this case, always well-defined? If yes, why do we not lay emphasis on this? If not, what are the examples? I tried defining a composite relation & it worked, but will it always work?
What I tried

Actually, there is a notion of composition of "relations" (which I prefer to call graphs, mainly because I'm used to). You can take a look at Pinter's A book of set theory. In Chapter 1 he defines the notion of composition of graphs (which is what you call relations). In a calculus we put no emphasis on this notion because we are primarily concerned with functions, not relations, except maybe when we are interested in implicit functions. But in other contexts, this notion of composition is useful.

Yes, given two relations $\mathcal{R} : A \leftrightarrow B, \mathcal{S} : B \leftrightarrow C$ you can always define the composite $\mathcal{R};\mathcal{S} : A \leftrightarrow C$ by $$a\ (\mathcal{R};\mathcal{S})\ c \Leftrightarrow \exists (b : B). a\ \mathcal{R}\ b \land b\ \mathcal{S}\ c$$
